# Hide option when aria-expand is false

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-select

I am trying to hide an option in mat-select only when aria-expanded is false..

I have an option for "Select All" and "Deselect All"  My problem is, when closed, it shows "Deselect All"

[aria-expanded = true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHzhz.png)

When closed:

[When aria-expanded = false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydyyS.png)

Is there an easy way to remove the option "Deselect All" from the closed state?

Comment: Could you share some code details to help you.
And did you try it https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#select-reset ?

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this:

```
<mat-select aria-expanded="false">
  <mat-option value="1" id="select">Select All</mat-option>
  <mat-option value="2">Option 2</mat-option>
</mat-select>

<style>
  mat-select[aria-expanded="false"] #select {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add mat-option without value

```
<mat-option>None</mat-option>
```

then can listen to selectionChange

```
(selectionChange)=change($event)
```

and clean selected values, when None is selected (value=undefined)

```
change(event) {
 console.log('Event: ', event.value);
 if (event.value.indexOf(undefined) != -1) {
   this.toppings.setValue('');
 }
 console.log(this.toppings.value);
}
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zn6jez?file=src/main.ts